# Ideas of Source of QualcommCameraHardware native_get_picture: MSM_CAM_IOCTL_GET_PICTURE Connection timed out error?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on a library to make the `Camera` API easier for developers to consume.

The Droid Incredible 2, in portrait mode, using the rear-facing camera, fails to take a picture. Specifically, I get this sequence in LogCat:

```
08-18 09:25:52.094: E/QualcommCameraHardware(1368): native_get_picture: MSM_CAM_IOCTL_GET_PICTURE fd 25 error Connection timed out
08-18 09:25:52.094: E/QualcommCameraHardware(1368): getPicture failed!
08-18 09:25:52.094: E/QualcommCameraHardware(1368): get picture failed, giving jpeg callback with NULL data
```

Those messages occur ~5 seconds after I call `takePicture()` on the `Camera`, which fits with some old source code I see for `QualcommCameraHardware` that sets up a 5000ms timeout on the `ioctl()` call to speak to the camera hardware.

The net result is that `onPictureTaken()` is passed a `null` `byte[]` of JPEG data, meaning we have no photo.

The device works with my code in all other tested configurations, including working in portrait mode with the front-facing camera.

Does anyone know of something specific that might cause this particular failure?

**UPDATE**

I can no longer reproduce the error. I would delete the question, but that apparently is not possible once there are answers.

Comment: Have you tried taking picture at low resolutions?

Comment: @AliImran: I will give that a try sometime, when I and my Incredible 2 are in the same place at the same time. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @AliImran: Capping the output at a lower resolution did indeed seem to help, though I was no longer getting this particular error and instead was simply getting corrupted output. Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone else is suffering from this problem, it may help to know the circumstances in which I'm receiving the same error.  Device is a Samsung Galaxy Mini (aka Europa), and the cause of the problem seems to be selecting a fixed (and relatively low) ISO setting while in low light.  I guess this makes the camera hardware actually take longer than the 5s timeout.  In this circumstance, however, I only get the first two lines of log from the quote above, and my PictureCallback is in fact never invoked (maybe this is a bug fixed in HTC's version but not Samsung's by invoking it with null?).

Comment: @CommonsWare: what approach you used to capture images from front camera ? using intent or using SurfaceView ?

Comment: @Jigs: You do not use a `SurfaceView` to capture images. I was using `android.hardware.Camera`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: for accessing front camera i used camera intent with 1 value ,but its not working  in all devices :/  then i used surface view which provide us surface to preview the camera angle and to access front camera .

Answer (score 1):

MSM_CAM_IOCTL_GET_PICTURE is a kernel call which runs the function

```
static int msm_get_pic(struct msm_sync *sync, void __user *arg)
```

I downloaded the kernel source for your device from the HTCdev and found the function defined in

```
drivers/media/video/msm/msm_camera-7x30.c
```

Could check what are the kernel messages when you take a picture?

```
adb shell su -c "dmesg"
```

Comment: ...and now I can't reproduce the problem. I must have changed something in my app for some other device, which had the side effect of fixing this issue. I'll delete the question in a day or two. My apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the `cameraService` which is part of the media process has crashed in the background. If you just try to run the default camera app in android and it does not show up then simply reboot the device to get this error off.

I think you are reusing picture callback for both raw and jpeg callbacks. So if it was called as raw callback, data could be null. Because the document says,

> Triggers an asynchronous image capture. The camera service will initiate a series of callbacks to the application as the image capture progresses. The shutter callback occurs after the image is captured. This can be used to trigger a sound to let the user know that image has been captured. The raw callback occurs when the raw image data is available (NOTE: the data will be null if there is no raw image callback buffer available or the raw image callback buffer is not large enough to hold the raw image). The postview callback occurs when a scaled, fully processed postview image is available (NOTE: not all hardware supports this). The jpeg callback occurs when the compressed image is available. If the application does not need a particular callback, a null can be passed instead of a callback method.

Comment: "I think you are reusing picture callback for both raw and jpeg callbacks" -- I am not supplying a raw callback at all (`null`), and I am requesting a JPEG image.